# Odoo - Python Programming Language

Tags: odoo-10

Employee Birthday List in QWeb Report :

Actually generate Qweb report  employees birthday list.

But print button is one model and fetch the report is one model.

How to access the employee details in qweb report ?

Comment: tell me how to access the other models data in qweb report in odoo

Comment: you can create method and call it in your qweb report...

Comment: how to call the method in qweb report ,give me example in odoo 10

Comment: Is the information related to the emplyee by m2o from the emplyee to The second model or the inverse

Answer (score 0):

in you model from where the print button is

```
@api.multi
def qweb_callmethod()
    return SomeValue
```

in Qweb report

```
<span t-esc ="o.qweb_callmethod()" />
```

Comment: for example my print button in view.xml : print_report

Comment: print button function                                                                                                            @api.multi                                                                                                                          def print_report(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                           here my question instead of print_report i used qweb_callmethod(),

Comment: but where i write our own method and how to call in print_report() function